# How to keep my QMainWindow always inside of the desktop?

Tags: qt, qmainwindow

I want to keep my `QMainWindow` always inside of the desktop, so I add the implementation for `QMainWindow::moveEvent` :

```
void MainWindow::moveEvent(QMoveEvent *ev)
{
    if(ev->pos().x() < 0) setGeometry(0, ev->oldPos().y(), width(), height());
}
```

But when I move the window to out of desktop left bounding, the app is crashed.
What is wrong with this code? Why it is crashed? Is my solution correct?

//--Update:
I tried with this:

```
int newx = ev->pos().x(),
        newy = ev->pos().y();
if(ev->pos().x() < 0) newx = 0;
if(ev->pos().y() < 0) newy = 0;
    move(newx, newy);
```

It worked without crash but I'm not satisfied because of the moving is not smooth.

Comment: You might be running into an infinite loop, as `setGeometry` will trigger another call to `moveEvent`. However I just tested this code and it worked fine for me!

Comment: thanks, I tried with `move`

Answer (score 2):

This should smoothly help with the upper left corner .. but you'll need to add some more conditions to get it working for all four sides.

`posX` and `posY` are member variables.

```
void MainWindow::moveStep() { // [SLOT]
   int movX = 0, movY = 0;
   if(posX < 0) movX = 1;
   if(posY < 0) movY = 1;
   move(posX + movX, posY + movY);
}


void MainWindow::moveEvent(QMoveEvent *ev) {

   if(ev->pos().x() < 0 || ev->pos().y() < 0) {
      posX = ev->pos().x();
      posY = ev->pos().y();
      QTimer::singleShot(10, this, SLOT(moveStep()));
   }
}
```

To have it even more elegantly consider using `QVariantAnimation` with a `QRect` and `setGeometry()`.

Comment: Made an important edit. Now it really works .. the window moves smoothly back into view if moved past the left screen border.

Comment: Consider using this mechanism to keep the window centered .. could by a nice effect .. or an annoying ; )