# How to animate changing widget position in QVBoxLayout

Tags: qt, animation, qvboxlayout

Widget position in QVBoxLayout can be changed by

```
layout->insertWidget(new_widget_position, 
                     layout->takeAt(current_widget_position)->widget())
```

I would like to animate widget position change in sliding animation.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible with a QBoxLayout.

But it is easily possible to layout manually using `setGeometry();`

This can be called continuously timer controlled with varying coordinates.

See this answers for related questions: [How to keep my QMainWindow always inside of the desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193956/how-to-keep-my-qmainwindow-always-inside-of-the-desktop/34197628#34197628) and [QSplitter in two directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202805/qsplitter-in-two-directions/34204253#34204253)

Or you can facilitate QPropertyAnimation to handle timing and start and end position for you.